# Spring Data JPA: search value object using raw value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have Entity which is defined with Value Object as field:

```
class CustomerEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
  private CustomerId customerId;

}
```

CustomerId is defined as Value Object:

```
class CustomerId implements Serializable {
  private final String value;
  //constructor, getter omitted for brewity
}
```

Repository is also easily defined and works well

```
interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, CustomerId> {
   Optional<Customer> findByCustomerId(CustomerId customerId);
}
```

How can I define Spring Data repository that I could search for customer on cusomter_id using String value?

```
Optional<Customer> findByCustomerIdStartsWith(String search);
```

Something similar to `SELECT * FROM Customers where customer_id like '?%'`? As far as I can understand I need to use custom JpaExpression with `@Query` annotation. But I can't figure out how can I cast Value Object field to string...

**UPD 1**
Have found workaround but it looks a bit ugly...

```
@Query("FROM CustomerEntity e where concat(e.customerId, '') like ?1%")
Optional<Customer> findByCustomerIdStartsWith(String search);
```

**UPD 2**

So I have found only way to make it work - to make Value Object as `@Embeddable` and use it within other objects as `@Embedded` with `@AttributeOverride`. Then solutions suggested in aswers will work. As a drawback I need to make empty constructor for Value Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) mentions `findByFirstnameLike`. Would findByCustomerIdLike work for you?

Also check out [advanced like](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.advanced-like) expressions.

The advanced like link mentions:
`@Query("select u from User u where u.firstname like %?1")` for `findByFirstnameEndsWith`.
So I thought it should work with

```
@Query("select c from Customer c where c.customerId.value like ?1%")

List<Customer> findByCustomerIdStartsWith(String id);
```

I did not expand the answer earlier as another answer mentioned something very similar when I was trying to add the details. I guess it should work with equals method implemented in CustomerId

Comment: unfortunately this will not work because Spring Data expects parameter to be of the type 'CustomerId'. It will throw following error: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%1234%] did not match expected type [com.mycompany.CustomerId (n/a)]`

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully it should work.

Comment: I'm getting follwing error: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: value`

Comment: value is the field on CustomerId class

Comment: Yes, it's there, both property and accessor `getValue()`. but still hibernate throws an error...

Answer (score 2):

Use a JPQL in the `@Query` and navigate to `CustomerId#value` using an accessor. Pass a named argument into the query using `@Param("search")` and refer to it as `:search` - it also works with `like 'something%'` construct.

```
@Query(SELECT * FROM Customers c where c.customerId.value like ':search%'")
Optional<Customer> findByCustomerIdStartsWith(@Param("search") String search);
```

Comment: I'm getting follwing error: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: value`